# How can a linear regression model give a low root mean square error but have a non well-behaved residuals vs fits plot?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, residuals

According to this [criteria](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat462/node/117/), a good residuals vs fits plot should look like this:

[image: good residuals]

A plot like this:

[image: residuals]

would not be considered a good linear model. Why would the model still give a low root mean square error on the training set?

Comment: what is the scale on the y-axis? that's what really matters for the calculation of the RMSE.  But you should certainly fix these problems before concluding the model is good ...

Answer (score 0):

If the second plot has the residual on the y-axis then the difference between it and the first plot is that in the first there appears to be no relationship between the spread (variance) of the residuals and the fitted value (or predicted response). In the second chart the residuals appear to have low variance (vertical spread is low) so the RMSE will be low but there's a relationship between what you're predicting and the residuals.

This usually indicates the model is misspecified in some way, perhaps you're missing a predictor that explains this relationship or perhaps there's autocorrelation such that the next output is dependent on previous outputs.

Most of the statistics such as confidence intervals of the coefficients assumes independent identically distributed residuals.